# Timer for Python 3.8.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

I need to create a timer that resets my slidingWindowSize variable without interrupting the application from running.

I have developed the server and client:

```
# Server
import socket
import sys
import config

MY_IP = config.myIP
OTHER_IP = config.otherIp
PORT_NUMBER = config.port_number

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = (MY_IP, PORT_NUMBER)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4097)

    print('received {} bytes from {}'.format(
        len(data), address))
    print(data)

    if data:
        sent = sock.sendto(data, address)
        print('sent {} bytes back to {}'.format(
            sent, address))


# Client
import socket
import sys
import config # My computer IP
import sched
import time

from threading import Timer

MY_IP = config.myIP # My IP 
PORT_NUMBER = config.port_number # Port Number

def timeout(slidingWindowSize):
    print('Window size value after:', time.time(), slidingWindowSize)
    exit()

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

# Create a UDP socket with my IP and Port
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = (MY_IP, PORT_NUMBER)
slidingWindowSize = 1

while True:
    print("Window size value before: ", slidingWindowSize)
    if slidingWindowSize == 128:
        exit()
    for i in range(slidingWindowSize):
        packet = bytes([1])
        # send data
        print('sending {!r}'.format(packet))
        sent = sock.sendto(packet, server_address)

    # Here I would need the timer to start, but it interrupts my algorithm.
    # (I have tried sched, but it didn't work)
    print('START:', time.time())
    scheduler.enter(3, 1, timeout, (slidingWindowSize,))
    #scheduler.run() -> tried to use it but it interrupted the algorithm

    for j in range(slidingWindowSize):
        # Receive response
        print('waiting to receive')
        data, server = sock.recvfrom(4097)
        print('received {!r}'.format(data))

    slidingWindowSize = slidingWindowSize * 2
    time.sleep(2)

sock.close()
```

What should I change in my code so that the timer won't stop the application from working and when it reaches timeout it sets slidingWindowSize to 1 again?

I have to implement the AIMD protocol where I will send the quantity of packets of my sliding window to other server, and while I don't lose any packet in the communication between a client and a server or the timer doesn't run out I will be increasing my sliding window.

All timers that I have found stop the application, I need a timer that starts counting while the application is working and when it reaches timeout or the application loses packets, sets the sliding window to 1 again.

Yes it will run forever..., but that is the objective, to analize the packet loss.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you actually want to do? What do you mean by "start the time?"

Comment: `sched.run()` is blocking, it will wait (using the `delayfunc()` function passed to the constructor). You can set `sched.run(blocking=False)`, give it a try if you haven't yet.

Comment: I have used time.time() to get the start time of the algorithm, then I stored it in a variable (timeStart) and created an if condition to compare if time().time() is bigger than the var (timeStart + 5). The value 5 would be the time of the timer.

Comment: ***"stored it in a variable (timeStart)"***: This isn't show in your questions code.

Comment: I am still testing the code, if it works I will post it, because I couldn't find another method that uses a timer in parallel with the application.